# How do I replace a letter that is 15 chars ahead of each other?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to replace each character a user inputs that is 15 letters ahead in the alphabet. For example, if a user inputs the word A, then it would output "P".

the word "AB" would output "PQ"  and so on with every word.

I've tried the following code but it is not working. I am thinking a loop may be the answer, but if anyone can think of some better ideas let me know.

```
alphabetArray = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz"];

function jumpAhead15(aString){
   aString.replace(alphabetArray[0][aString + 15]);
}

jumpAhead15("hi");
```

Comment: And what would "ST" return?  Does it wrap around? Also, how do you want to deal with upper and lower case?

Comment: Yes, it wraps around so that at any point of the alphabet, you will always be replacing the string 15 characters ahead.

Comment: How do you want to deal with upper and lower case?

Comment: If it is uppercase then it should return uppercase and vice versa. so if you put in aB, then it should come out to pQ

Answer (score 3):

You could take the string as iterable and get an array of characters and replace any character by getting the index and the offset, adjusted by the remainder of the length of the alphabet.

The [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) returns the rest of a division:

> The remainder operator returns the remainder left over when one operand is divided by a second operand. It always takes the sign of the dividend.

The function is here to keep the index for the getting the character of `alphabet` in a valid range. For example by taking index `20` and the wanted shift of `15`, you get `35` which is not an index of `alphabet`. by using the remainder operator you get the value of `9` which is the rest of `35 / 26 = 1 rest 9`

Then return the character and join the array to a final string.

Method used:

- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which takes two arguments, one iterable or an object with a length property and a mappring function, which is called for every element of the new array. (`c` is the first parameter of the callback and denotes here a single character)
- [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as callback for `Array.from`

```js
function jumpAhead15(aString) {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz";
    return Array
        .from(
            aString,
            c => alphabet[(alphabet.indexOf(c) + 15) % alphabet.length]
        )
        .join('');
}
console.log(jumpAhead15("hi"));
console.log(jumpAhead15("ab"));
```

Comment: What is the function of the modulus operator in this instance?

Comment: Also, what does the letter  c=> do in this instance? I don't see the letter c being referenced anywhere.

Comment: I am guessing you made a function using the letter 'c' from the ".from" method. In the ".from" method you have 2 inputs, aString, and then the return function.

Comment: I guess I did a simpler to understand but less simple code if you want to understand the process better http://jsfiddle.net/Ph0b0x/5phvy683/17/ I will stick to this answer tho.

Comment: @Ph0b0x: a quick note on your Fiddle: you really need to move the definition of `newWord` inside `jumpAhead15`.  Otherwise you will keep accumulating on every call.

Comment: Thanks Scott. You are right. Also, global variables are no a best practices. I was just playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

With `alphabetArray` as above, try:

```
aString.split("").map(letter => alphabetArray[(alphabetArray.indexOf(letter) + 15) % 26]).join("");
```

That is: convert the string to an array of 1-letter strings, replace each letter by the one 15 places further along (wrapping if necessary, hence the modulus operator `%`), then join the letters back together into one string.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the answer from Nina hard to understand, then this one may not be for you either, but here is a function that is built on a more generic letter rotation scheme.  It also handles differences in case:

```js
const rotate = (configs) => (str) => str.split('').map(
  c => configs.reduce(
    (s, [letters, offset]) => {
      const idx = letters.indexOf(s);
      return idx < 0 ? s : letters[(idx + offset) % letters.length]
    },
    c
  )
).join('')

const by15 = rotate([
  [[...'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'], 15],
  [[...'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'], 15]
])

console.log(by15('ab'))            //~> 'pq'
console.log(by15('aB'))            //~> 'pQ'
console.log(by15('Hello, world!')) //~> 'Wtaad, ldgas!'
```

This uses the same basic technique with the modulus operator, modified slightly to return the original character if it's not in our list.  We do this for each alphabet supplied, in this case, the upper- and lower-case letters.  This only works if the different alphabets have no overlap.  We pass the offset together with each alphabet, in case you want to, for instance, rotate digits by 3 and letters by 15.  If you didn't want to do this, you could move the offset out of the `configs` parameter (in which case it might be called `alphabets`) and make the single offset a second parameter for `rotate`.

Note the structure: `rotate` is an arrow function which returns an arrow function.  So to get a useful function out of it, you need to call it with the alphabet configuration.  The function returned just takes a string and returns the rotated string.

This is not the most efficient solution, as you have to loop through each alphabet, even once you've found it.  Since I wouldn't expect it to be used with many alphabets, this seems a good tradeoff for relatively clean code.  But one could easily write a version which searched through until it found an alphabet that contained your character and then worked on that one.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.